# VBA code in excel to copy a field and paste into a new outlook email

Tags: excel, outlook, office-automation, vba7

I currently have a vba code that is activated by a button in excel that copies certain information from the sheet into an outlook email.
Having updated to win64 and updating the declare statements etc. I can not get it to open an outlook email window.
What is the new code to open the outlook application window from within excel via win64

Comment: Can you post your current code please

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The following code works like a charm on my machine with Office x64 installed:

```
Dim applOL As Outlook.Application
Dim miOL As Outlook.MailItem

'Create a new instance of the Outlook application. Set the Application object as follows:
Set applOL = New Outlook.Application
'create mail item:
Set miOL = applOL.CreateItem(olMailItem)
 
With miOL
 .To = "name@domain.com"
 .Subject = "Mail Automation"
 .Body = "Sending the Active Excel Workbook as attachment!"
 'add host workbook as an attachment to the mail:
 .Attachments.Add ActiveWorkbook.FullName
 .Display
End With

'clear the object variables:
Set applOL = Nothing
Set miOL = Nothing
```

Don't forget to add an Outlook COM reference in your VBA environment.

Also you may find the following articles helpful:

- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)
- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)

Also take a look at the [Automating Outlook from Other Office Applications](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-other-office-applications) article.